# Insert dynamic field values to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have dynamic input fields shown in the form if value `Others- Not Listed` is selected from the dropdown menu. I am trying to then insert those values to mysql table called `courses_selection_list` through php pdo.  I will be inserting both `course_id` and `course_name`. This values are inside div `.hideNewCourse`. But not sure how to do so since the values are inside dynamic input fields. Live [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/courses_stat.php)

```
<form>
<div id="course_catalog">
<div id="course_1">
<label>Course # 1</label>
<br>
<label>Course Name:</label>
<select id="coursename_1" class="course_list" name="coursename_1">
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>
<option value="1">Math</option>
<option value="2">English</option>
<option value="3">Science</option>
<option value="4">Other- Not Listed</option>
</select>
<div class="hideNewCourse" style="">
Add Course Name to List:
<input id="new_course_name_50" class="new_course_name" type="text" name="new_course_name[]">
<input id="new_course_id_50" class="new_course_id" type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="new_course_id[]" value="50">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="course_2">
<label>Course # 2</label>
<br>
<label>Course Name:</label>
<select id="coursename_2" class="course_list" name="coursename_2">
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>
<option value="1">Math</option>
<option value="2">English</option>
<option value="3">Science</option>
<option value="4">Other- Not Listed</option>
</select>
<div class="hideNewCourse" style="">
Add Course Name to List:
<input id="new_course_name_51" class="new_course_name" type="text" name="new_course_name[]">
<input id="new_course_id_51" class="new_course_id" type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="new_course_id[]" value="51">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Table: `courses_selection_list`

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| course_id |    course_name    |
+-----------+-------------------+
|         1 | Math              |
|         2 | English           |
|         3 | Science           |
|         4 | Other- Not Listed |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in order to submit those values to your table:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//I used `new_course_name` as the loop termination condition, 
//but any of the 2 keys would have worked
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['new_course_name']); $i++) {
    $new_course_name = $_POST['new_course_name'][$i];
    $new_course_id = $_POST['new_course_id'][$i];

//here, inside the loop, run the database query using the 2 values above    
$query_init3 = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO courses_selection_list (course_id, course_name) VALUES(:new_course_id, :new_course_name);");
$query_init3->execute(array(
    "new_course_id" => $new_course_id,
    "new_course_name" => $new_course_name
));
}
}
```